# Why the obj is being mutated when I am modifying the cloned obj ( using {...})?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, mutation, spread-syntax

Lets take an object d.

```
var d =  { 
  "e":{
    "f": 3
  }
}
```

Now copying `d` to `t` with {...} and assigning new prop.

```
var t = {...d}
t.e._f = 4
```

Why the object d is being mutated to

```
{
  "e": Object {
    "_f": 4,
    "f": 3
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing shallow copy. `{...d}` is equivalent to `Object.assign({}, d)` which in turn copies properties **one** level deep. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

> For deep cloning, we need to use other alternatives because
>   Object.assign() copies property values. If the source value is a
>   reference to an object, it only copies that reference value.

So `t.e === d.e` referencing the same object.